# Angular: Matching height of div with div inside component

Tags: html, angular, components, height

I have a home-component which displays an aside-component and a div.
Those two should be displayed next to each other with the same height.
(The div inside the home-component shoud match the height of the div inside the aside-component)

I got a working solution attached where i used a "display: contents" on the app-aside tag. This is not a usable solution, since its not supported by Edge.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkgwsb

i also tried "display:table" and "display: table-cell" which is also not working.

---

#### app.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <app-aside></app-aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### app.component.css

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 840px;
}
```

#### aside.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

#### aside.component.css

```
.sidebar {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 360px;
}
```

Both Divs (content and sidebar) should have the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `aside` element has the same height as your `.content` div, because of the display: flex on the container. The problem is the sidebar div inside the `app-aside` component. Remove the .sidebar div (and style the app-aside using the `:host {}` selector in the css) OR add `height: 100%` to the .sidebar div.

Comment: Wow this is embarrassing :D
I tried this before but because I had a "padding-top" on the aside component aswell it didn't appear as the same height.
Thank you so much